# php sort array within array by matching keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, matching

I searched for my related topic, but didn't find a similar issue.

I have an array within an array and I have an array which I define as my ordering array.

```
[array1] => Array
    (
        [23456] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [info] => info
            )
        [78933] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [info] => info
            )
    )
```

and so on....

```
    [orderarray] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78933
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23456
            )
    )
```

I would like to reorder array1 keys by the value of orderarray id.

So the first key should be then 78933 and not like in array1 23456.
Does anybody knows how to continue this?

I know to read the keys from array1.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key)
{
   echo $key;
}

foreach ($orderarray as $key)
{
   foreach ($key as $id => val)
   {
      echo $val;
   }
}
```

So how can I merge both foreach together the best way?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom key-sort function using `uksort()`

```
<?php

$array = array(
   "23456" => array("id" => 1, "info" => "info"),
   "78933" => array("id" => 1, "info" => "info")
);

$orderarray = array(
    array("id" => 78933),
    array("id" => 23456)
);

function customSort($a, $b) {
    global $orderarray;
    $_a = 0; $_b = 0;
    foreach ($orderarray as $index => $order) {
        $oid = intval($order['id']);
        if ($oid == intval($a)) $_a = $index;
        if ($oid == intval($b)) $_b = $index;
    }
    if ($_a == $_b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($_a < $_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uksort($array, "customSort");
print_r($array);

?>
```